# In C/C++ on linux, how do I create a prelocked mutex

Tags: c++, c, linux, pthreads, mutex

What attribute do I use to create a pthreads mutex that is locked by the creating thread at creation time?

Comment: Your name is awesome.  Best of luck in your quest for answers.

Comment: Such a mechanism doesn't seem to exist. If you could elaborate on your need for such a requirement, people of SO could help you solve it.

Comment: What purpose would such a method serve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no observably-distinct difference between a mutex that is created in the locked state, and one that is created and subsequently locked by the thread that creates it. That is, if you write (hypothetical):

```
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &prelocked_attr);
/* done */
```

versus

```
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, 0);
pthread_mutex_lock(&done);
/* done */
```

In both cases, it's UB for any other thread to attempt in any way to access the mutex before the creating thread reaches the "done" comment and subsequently performs some action that could let other threads know the mutex exists.

The fact that you think you need a pre-locked mutex suggests **strongly** to me that you're trying to do something very very wrong, and probably invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Sorry, SO wouldn't let me post my comment. No idea why.  @R Mostly asked as an academic question.  I seem to remember seeing a reference to prelocked mutexes, but it might have been to preset semaphores.  In either case, I use an stl vector to track activity in several threads.  The master thread was dutifully checking that the "time" stored by each thread was incrementing.  I thought I had a race condition where master thread was checking a thread node before it updates.  Wasn't the problem.  Adding a mutex to the node was a thought for preventing the master looking too quickly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear to be supported by the pthreads mutex interfaces. You're going to have to mutually lock it, and use some other synchronization method to keep other threads from grabbing it before you do (which is what I'm assuming you want to do here), in semi-pseudocode below:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(my_pthread_creation_mutex);

pthread_mutex_init(new_mutex, mutex_attributes);
pthread_mutex_lock(new_mutex);

pthread_mutex_unlock(my_pthread_creation_mutex);
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get with what you want is to use semaphores. They can be initialized with a specific value. On linux (as you have that tag) `man sem_overview` should give you a good introduction to that topic

Comment: This answer is correct, but it's still subject to the same concerns I mentioned in my answer, namely that if OP needs such a thing, the code is probably wrong, because there's no way correct code can need it. (On the other hand, with *named* semaphores this could work, since `O_EXCL|O_CREAT` can do the necessary synchronization for you.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If you need to do that, you will have to lock it before allowing other threads access to it. You will have to do something like that anyway, to prevent other threads accessing it before initialisation is complete.